# How can I boot back into Ubuntu after Windows 10 upgrade?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I had been running Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1 happily along each other on a Lenovo Yoga 2 for a period of months. Even after an initial Windows 10 upgrade this continued, until last night. Since last night, the computer always boots directly into Windows, even booting from USB seems impossible - which then stops me from running the usual boot repair tools

I checked the BIOS and it looks ok to me. Secure boot is off, the UEFI boot order is: USB, Ubuntu, Windows (all of which appear in the menu). I turned off fast boot in the Windows power options.

I can only assume Windows 10 did something to my computer last night, but I cannot figure out what. How do I restore the grub boot loader if USB boot is not working either?

Comment: I'd try making an Ubuntu LiveUSB, booting from it, and then running `sudo update-grub` on `sda`.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found an odd solution in Windows.

Go to Settings -> Updates & Recovery, and look around until you find advanced boot options. Click restart now, and choose Ubuntu. That should work

Comment: That seems pretty warm, but not hot enough. I have Settings -> Updates & security -> Recovery -> Advanced startup -> Restart now. That triggers a menu on boot showing an option to boot from device, which includes an "ubuntu" option. But that starts Windows again. I'll try booting from USB that way.

Comment: For the record:; booting via USB works this way. My USB key doesn't have boot-repair, nor does the WiFi work. I'll make a custom one tonight (+12h) and report back.

Comment: @PeterBecker Maybe Windows decided to do something very odd to GRUB. Maybe boot from the USB, chroot into the Ubuntu partition on your hard drive, and reinstall grub.

Comment: I agree, it sounds like GRUB is damaged. If you haven't already done so, [disable the Windows Fast Startup feature.](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) This feature turns a Windows shutdown into a suspend-to-disk, which can cause filesystem damage for any shared filesystems, including the ESP where GRUB is stored.

Comment: @FireFaced: I upvoted since it was definitely useful, but it's not quite a complete answer yet