# HP Pavilion G6 - efibootmgr changes get overwritten at next reboot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, hp

I am having trouble getting my HP Pavilion G6 to use the boot order I specify using efibootmgr --bootorder, as seen on this thread.

I want to see grub (it's installed, and efibootmgr shows ubuntu at 0002) at boot time.

Instead, no matter what I do, the boot boot order seems to be rewritten at reboot back to the initial setting (3002,3003,3006,2001,2002), so the machine boots to windows.

default boot order is 3002,3003,3006,2001,2002 (windows is 3002, and grub is at 0003 but not on the boot order list after I installed ubuntu on a partition.)

```
sudo efibootmgr --bootnext 0003
```

This works, but only for the next reboot.

```
sudo efibootmgr --bootorder 0003,3002,3003,3006,2001,2002
```

This does not work - upon the next reboot, it boots to windows 10 (3002) and efibootmgr reports the boot order is back to default as shown above. After doing the efibootmgr --bootorder command, I re-run efibootmgr and the boot order is what I want, but it doesn't actually work (the machine changes it back to 3002,3003,3006,2001,2002 and uses this as the boot order upon rebooting.)

```
sudo efibootmgr --bootorder 0003
```

Same as above.

(this is similar to the following posting, but I was told not to ask there.)

[How to dual boot Windows 10, and Ubuntu on a HP Pavilion G6?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783654/how-to-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-on-a-hp-pavilion-g6/1251338#1251338)

Comment: Just about everyone with HP seems to have this issue. Some have posted that UEFI update and then changing boot order in UEFI settings works. The use of efibootmgr which grub also uses to install, does not work. There may be other settings also as disabling Optane or UEFI Security settings that should be reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

During the initial moments after powering on the device, take the option to enter "Setup" (for example: press F12 immediately after device powers on).
Navigate to the Boot menu.
Change the EFI boot order.
Save and exit.

Comment: I was having the same issue as @wb0gaz.  Oldfred's comment inspired the realization that although efibootmgr is designed to modify the EFI boot order from the comfort of your Linux terminal, when that doesn't work, we must become courageous and use the built-in UEFI user interface.