# Ubuntu not detecting Windows 10 during installation

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, 20.04, usb-installation

When I try to install Ubuntu 20.04 (or 18.04), it doesn't give me an option to install alongside Windows, instead, it just says:

> This computer currently has no detected operating systems

My fastboot is also disabled - which seems to be the solution for about everyone who faced this issue.

Comment: How have to created bootale USB ?

Comment: Also check, https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Comment: @DigvijayS Yeah, created it using Rufus

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Did you also change to AHCI from RAID or Intel RST? But you need Windows driver for AHCI first if that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Manually create the partitions. Choose Something Else in the menu. Now click on the Unallocated/Free space and click + button. Then set mountpoint as / and filesystem as ext4. This is the root partition. And click it and install Ubuntu there.

Comment: I have freed 75 GB from my C drive but when I open Ubuntu installation, it shows upwards of 80 GB. Could this cause any issues?
Also, do I need to create partitions for swap and home (as explained here: https://askubuntu.com/a/783957/1007302)?
I am fairly new to doing this manually, so I'm not sure how to proceed...

Comment: You should have freed up some space from primary partition of disk to install ubuntu, if not do it. And use that to install ubuntu.

Comment: Have freed space on the primary partition only.

Comment: Then use that, make sure that is unallocated (unformatted space)

Comment: It is unallocated. Will I need swap and home partitions? And will there be any issues because Ubuntu is showing more free than there is?

Comment: No, only creating the root partition is enough. The rest will be done by the system for tasks such as sizing home and swap.